# C++ Error: No Member in Class?

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11

I'm working on C++, and this is just a very basic program, but I'm still getting an error.

**The error message is:**

> 'class secondary' has no member named 'getting'.

Why is this? It works for my void setting, but not for getting? What am I doing wrong here?

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "secondary.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    secondary s;
    int scale;
    cout << "On a scale of 1-10, how awesome are you?" << endl;
    cin >> scale;
    cout << endl;

    s.setting(scale);
    cout << s.getting();
    return 0;
}
```

*secondary.h*

```
#ifndef SECONDARY_H
#define SECONDARY_H
#include <string>


class secondary
{
    public:
        void setting(int x);
        string getting();
};

#endif // SECONDARY_H
```

*secondary.cpp*

```
#include "secondary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void secondary::setting(int x){
    factor = x;
}

string secondary::getting(){
    string result;
    if(factor < 3){
        result = "You have a very low self esteem.";
    }elseif(factor > 3){
        if(factor > 7){
            result = "You have a very high self esteem."
        }else{
            result = "You have a medium self esteem."
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private factor;
```

Comment: I think the problem must be related to the fact that you wrote `string` instead of `std::string`. Is there not an error message about that, too?

Comment: No. Inclusively, I've used string before, and I've never encountered this error. It's just recently that I started working with different classes in different files.

Comment: I did what you said, but now I'm getting a new error saying "factor" was not declared in the scope.

Comment: Your declaration of `factor` is invalid. You must move it inside the class in order to make it a class member. Also, you gave `factor` no type. Also, `private` can't be used as a specifier on a member declaration; it has to be followed by a colon, marking the following members as private. You should probably pick up a good C++ book.

Comment: After a lot of errors I finally got the program to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brian The missing semicolons were also an issue when I went deeper in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, looking at this again, and deeper, this code has many issues (semicolons missing at key points and the `private int` definition should have been in the header file, not the cpp file 9t(private is its own section, see below):The problem, from what I can see, `s` has not yet been instantiated yet, do so and the operation should work correctly.

Please also note that when factor was defined in the cpp file, it was defined at bottom, it should actually be defined before any use of the variable to be defined (in the header file is better meet with common/conventional coding standards).

Please check this tested code:

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "secondary.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    secondary s;
    int scale;
    cout << "On a scale of 1-10, how awesome are you?" << endl;
    cin >> scale;
    cout << endl;

    s.setting(scale);
    cout << s.getting();
    return 0;
}
```

*secondary.h*

```
#ifndef SECONDARY_H
#define SECONDARY_H
#include <string>

class secondary
{
public:
    void setting(int x);
    std::string getting();

private: // Note: this is how you do private
    int factor; // This is the definition with type int, missing in original
};

#endif // SECONDARY_H
```

*secondary.cpp*

```
#include "secondary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void secondary::setting(int x){
    factor = x;
}

string secondary::getting(){
    string result;
    if (factor < 3){
        result = "You have a very low self esteem.";
    }else if(factor > 3){
        if (factor > 7){
            result = "You have a very high self esteem.";
        }
        else{
            result = "You have a medium self esteem.";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: secondary s; is perfectly fine - it creates an instance of setting on the stack

Comment: @pm100 got busy in group/team chat that will end soon, going to update my answer again soon.

Comment: @pm100 Digging into it further, I did spot numerous issues that should be fixed in the above code.

Comment: Never put `using namespace std;` (or for any other namespace) into a header.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Are you suggesting that using `std::string` is also invalid? A clarification why you think that is an issue  would be appreciated, I will update that in code in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: Write `std::string` when you want a string. Do not put `using std::string;` into a header. Use Google to see why it's a bad idea; the ink already spilt on this topic is plentiful.

Comment: @Potatoswatter That issue is resolved, no other code issue has been pointed out to me since, therefore, it is unclear how this is worth a negative rating? Are you/others seeing something else as an issue not mentioned yet?